# onClick JavaScript button --- Add simple If condition

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am kinda new person in JavaScript, please help me our here with small doubt

What I am missing here ........ I want to correct this one....

**I am trying this :**

```
if( {!Account.CID__c}){
    window.open( '{! SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSetting__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.AnotherField__C)}');
}
else{
 window.open( '{! SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSetting__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.CID__c )}')
}
```

> GOT ERROR "Unexpected Token )"

**Earlier I was having**

```
window.open( '{!SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSettings__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.CID__c)}');
```

**And I just want to add one more Condition here i.e.**

```
If(CID__C == null){
  // put another AnotherField__C in place of that.
}else{ 
   //put Account.CID__C ...which we were having earlier 
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396999/onclick-javascript-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to this:

```
if( '{!Account.CID__c}' == 'null' || '{!Account.CID__c}' == ''){
    window.open( '{! SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSetting__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.AnotherField__C)}');
}
else {
    window.open( '{! SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSetting__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.CID__c )}')
}
```